# Visual Studio 2017 Migrating packages.config to PackageReference

Tags: visual-studio-2017, migration, teamcity, packagereference

When migrating `packages.config` with `Newtonsoft.Json` package to the `PackageReference` csproj format I get compatibility issue:

> Newtonsoft.Json v10.0.3, install.ps1 script will be ignored when the package is installed after the migration.

Is this anything which could break something? The project compiles well in local VS 2017. But TeamCity Visual Studio (sln) build fails with the error `namespace name Newtonsoft could not be found`. Can this be related somehow to the migration issue?

Comment: What is your NuGet version in TeamCity?

Comment: @Peska Good question. It was 3.4.3 version which doesn't work with PackageReferences. When Nuget 4.3.0 was used for Nuget Restore it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Peska's comment I've checked the NuGet version which was used for the Restore build step in TeamCity. The used NuGet version was 3.4.3.

Once this was changed to Nuget 4.3.0 the package restore worked as expected and the following "Build Solution (sln)" step then succeeded.